# Entityform submission custom view

Tags: entities

I created an entityform and a view which displays all previous submissions in a table format. On each row of this table I have a link to view a specific submission which target to a page with this kind of url /?q=entityform/submissionID.

I would like to customise the display of this link and retrieve user information and incorporate a private msg form to reply to the submitter. Lets say that my list of previous submissions were products. I would like that the current logged in user could contact the seller on that page (by private msg)
Is that possible?

thanks in advance for any help that will be provided

Comment: Your question is too broad, please attempt to make it more specific. For example, what criteria would you use to customize each submission?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Ok So basically I want to use each submission as a starting point to make a reply. So I would like to retrieve user information and incorporate a private msg form to reply to the submitter. Lets say that my list of previous submissions were products. I would like that the current logged in user could contact the seller on that page (by private msg).